# Unable to wrap `driver.execute_script()` within `explicit wait` condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've created a python script together with selenium to parse a specific content from a webpage. I can get this result `AARONS INC` located under `QUOTE` in many different ways but the way I wish to scrape that is by using ***`pseudo selector`*** which unfortunately selenium doesn't support. The commented out line within the script below represents that selenium doesn't support `pseudo selector`.

However, when I use `pseudo selector` within `driver.execute_script()` then I can parse it flawlessly. To make this work I had to use hardcoded delay for the element to be avilable. Now, I wish to do the same wrapping this `driver.execute_script()` within `Explicit Wait` condition.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get("https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:AAN")
time.sleep(15)
# item = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span:contains('AARONS')")))
item = driver.execute_script('''return $('span:contains("AARONS")')[0];''')
print(item.text)
```

***How can I wrap `driver.execute_script()` within Explicit Wait condition?***

Comment: what's the pseudo selector here? Why can't you use xpath with contains text?

Comment: This is `:contains()` @supputuri. I didn't say I can't use xpath to achieve that. However, my question is about wrapping `driver.execute_script()` within explicit wait.

Comment: I see the other options to handle this, however I provided the answer to meet your requirement. Check and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the ways you can achieve that. Give it a shot.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get('https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:AAN')

    item = wait.until(
        lambda driver: driver.execute_script('''return $('span:contains("AARONS")')[0];''')
    )
    print(item.text)
```

Comment: Doesnt works in:
`wait.until( lambda driver: driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", dep))`
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You could do the while thing in the browser script which is probably safer:

```
item = driver.execute_async_script("""
  var span, interval = setInterval(() => {
    if(span = $('span:contains("AARONS")')[0]){
      clearInterval(interval)
      arguments[0](span)
    }
  }, 1000)
""")
```

Comment: This is quite impressive @pguardiario.

Comment: The only and main problem with this approach is that the script will keep running forever if the selector is faulty or the element is not present. So, timeout option is necessary to make it flawless @pguardiario.

Comment: Yes, if the element is not always be there, just increment a counter and return false or something.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple approach.

```
url = 'https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:AAN'
driver.get(url)
# wait for the elment to be presented
ele = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('''return $('span:contains("AARONS")')[0];'''))
# print the text of the element
print (ele.text)
```